# How to write unit test case for REST API method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, rest

I have rest api methods in controller which directly call database methods and sql response directly in json format to client. Following is one of example

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [Route(RouteConfig.Routes.LovList.contactStatus)]
    public IHttpActionResult ContactStatusList()
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(new Models.Response(
                        Models.ResponseMessages.Success,
                        new DBClass.HeroDb().GetList(
                            DBClass.DBConstants.ListConstants.query_Contact_Status))
                     );
        }
        catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
        
    }
```

**GetList()** is db function which list out some drop down list from database. But now i don't know how to write unit test case for this method of controller of REST API. Please suggest some example.

Comment: Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy  i clearly mentioned about db function. Response coming from db function from sql server . above doc doesn't provide details regarding db function unit testing.